# SQL Countifs and Sumifs Function

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, sumifs, case-when

I have a table like this

```
Queries          Query Cat.           Item Name          Item Cat.          Item Sold          Stock Avail.
iPhone 6         Mobile Phone         iPhone 6           Mobile Phone       20                 10
iPhone 6         Mobile Phone         iPhone 6 XS        Mobile Phone       10                 20
iPhone 6         Mobile Phone         iPhone 6 S         Mobile Phone       5                  20
iPhone 6         Phone Accessories    iPhone 6 S Case    Phone Accessories  200                100
iPhone 6         Phone Accessories    iPhone 6 Earphone  Earphone           150                200
iPhone 6         Phone Accessories    iPhone 6 Charger   Phone Wall Charger 100                250
iPhone 6         Mobile Phone         iPhone 6 S Plus    Mobile Phone       15                 15
```

And I want a table like below where:

1. I want to count how many item that CONTAINS queries keywords under specific keywords (not exact match). In Excel it was using COUNTIFS(item_name,"*(query name)*", array_item_cat, query_cat)
2. I want to sum total of item sold under item that CONTAINS queries keywords under specific keywords (not exact match). In Excel it was using SUMIFS(array_item_sold,item_name,"*(query name)*", array_item_cat, query_cat)
3. I want to sum total remaining available stock under item that CONTAINS queries keywords under specific keywords (not exact match). In Excel it was using SUMIFS(array_stock_avail,item_name,"*(query name)*", array_item_cat, query_cat)

This is the table that I want:

```
Queries           Query Cat.          Item Count          Total Item Sold           Total Stock
iPhone 6          Mobile Phone        4                   50                        65
iPhone 6          Phone Accessories   1                   200                       100
```

And I was using this queries:

```
And I was using this queries:
SELECT  queries_keyword
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN item_name LIKE queries_keyword AND item_cat = query_cat THEN 1 END) AS count_item_queries
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN item_name LIKE queries_keyword AND item_cat = query_cat THEN item_sold END) AS Total Item Sold
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN item_name LIKE queries_keyword AND item_cat = query_cat THEN stock_available END) AS Total Stock
FROM   my_table
GROUP BY queries_keyword
```

I was using LIKE so that it won't only shows exact match similar like when you are using IN or "=", but LIKE needs to use wildcard '%%' to work on any item name that CONTAINS, and above query logic, the LIKE function become the same as IN or "-" because I'm not using wildcard.

On a side note, I'm not using wildcard due to there are millions of data queries, and millions of item, so I want it to be automatically counting and summing for me, rather than I have to input it one by one using wildcard '%%'.

Can anyone please help to suggest better and exact query for this problem? I'm new on using SQL, spare me :(

Comment: You are talking about matching *something* to keywords, but I just don't get what is being matched to what.  What keywords are you talking about?  Where do they come from?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is somewhat hard to follow.  But your results suggest that you are looking for something like this:

```
select queries, queries_cat, sum(item_sold), sum(item_stock)
from t
where query_cat = item_cat
group by queries, queries_cat;
```

And this logic may be what you are trying to describe.